# .Net Core service is not getting registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have the following two classes with interface

```
public interface IInterface1
{
 //declarations
}

public class class1 : IInterface1
{
 //definitions
}

public interface IInterface2
{
//declarations
}

public class class2 : IInterface2
{
   private readonly IInterface1 _interface;
   //constructor
   public class2(IInterface1 interface1)
   {
     //getting null for interface1
     _interface = interface1;
   }
}
```

and a controller where i'm injecting the **IInterface2**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
  private readonly IInterface2 _usecase;
  public MyController(IInterface2 usecase)
  {
    _usecase = usecase;
  }
}
```

and in Startup.cs i have registered service like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddScoped<IInterface2, class2>();
  services.AddScoped<IInterface1, class1>(x => (class1)x.GetService<IInterface1>());
}
```

the issue which facing is when i'm injecting the **IInterface1** in **class2** not able to access the properties of the interface1 in constructor instead getting null

Comment: cause i need to inherit in multiple classes so thought it better to create a interface instead on inheriting the whole class since need to access only few methods of of class 1

Comment: Isn't that working simply with `services.AddScoped<IInterface1, class1>()` ? (the dependency system will also inject for the dependencies themselves, except of course when there is a circular dependency)

Comment: @Pac0 no it's not getting error of circular dependency

Comment: which error exactly ?

Comment: @Pac0 circular dependency since in class1 there are few more injection is happening like IConnectionFactory and IConnection

Comment: Then your problem is to solve the circular dependency. The MCVE you showed above is working well, no error with it (using the line I wrote above to inject class1). I don't think there is enough info in the question currently.

Comment: note that the line you wrote creates access violation (infinite recursion) : `services.AddScoped<IInterface1, class1>(x => (class1)x.GetService<IInterface1>())` : Basically you tell the dependency system : "Whenever you need an `Interface1`, you will inject a `class1`, and the rule to get this `class1` is to ask yourself to get an `Interface1`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you showed in the question works well if you replace the configuration with this :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddScoped<IInterface2, class2>();
  services.AddScoped<IInterface1, class1>();
}
```

Note that the line you wrote :

```
services.AddScoped<IInterface1, class1>(x => (class1)x.GetService<IInterface1>())
```

is causing `Access Violation`

(Because, when `Interface1` is needed, dependency system will try to get ... an `Interface1` from the dependency system using `GetService`, executing this rule in an infinite recursion)

We need more details to understand your problem and help solving it.

You may need to create a factory for your classes, or solve the circular dependency you mentionned in comments, that apparently prevents you from using the simple injection shown here.

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes i think i need to create a factory for classes to resolve this